# bundle is invalid. not accepting applications built with this version of the sdk

Tags: iphone, ios

i am looking for a way to upload/validate an app for ios. i am using xcode 4.2 and latest ios sdk is iOS 5. but i got the message:

> bundle is invalid. not accepting applications built with this version
>   of the sdk

what may be the reason? any ideas?

**[update]** deployment target: 4.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check if you are still using a beta version of xcode... if you installed it when iOS5 was still in beta you get a not-for-appstore version of xcode (and library). I know this 'cause i got the same error in the past and have to keep 2 different versions of XCode, one for testing iOS5 functionality and another for distribuition.
My suggestion: download the latest XCode.