# Error Submitting App to Appstore

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5, app-store

We are getting following error when we try to validate our app.

"This bundle is invalid. Apple is not currently accepting applications built with this version of the SDK."

Our Xcode is  4.3 Build 4D1002.

Base SDK 5.0

Can you please let me know the solution?

Comment: Compile your app against 5.1 and resubmit.

Comment: Which is the lowest targeted version of iOS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [bundle is invalid. not accepting applications built with this version of the sdk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245319/bundle-is-invalid-not-accepting-applications-built-with-this-version-of-the-sdk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`App-Store doesn't accept apps which are compiled with Beta versions of the SDK`

You need to check if you are using beta version of the SDK.

Please check it and let me know if you need more help.

Refer to this link:

[bundle is invalid. not accepting applications built with this version of the sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245319/bundle-is-invalid-not-accepting-applications-built-with-this-version-of-the-sdk)

Refer to the link here: http://www.redmondpie.com/download-5.1-beta-3-for-iphone-ipad-ipod-touch-ota-devs-only/. It says `The first beta release of iOS 5.1 also saw the release of Xcode 4.3 (build 4D1002) to developers.`

So I would suggest you to use a fully released version of Xcode (may be Xcode 4.2) and then submit your app using that.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the actual Xcode (with the final-version of iOS 5.1) and set the Base SDK to the latest one. You can reach backward-compatibility with the Deployment Target.

Answer (score 0):

Here's things I've covered;

No memory leaks
Tested performance on an actual device
Doesn't crash :)
Using correct certificates / profile
What I'm a little unsure about are how to configure the "Bundle Display Name" /"Bundle Identifier" and "Bundle Name" in info.plist. I understand the first is the text that's shown on the iPhone itself, but what about the last? Does this have to match Bundle Identifier?

Are there any other things I should add to the info.plist? I've noticed that when built for Adhoc distribution my app does not have any author/title information in iTunes.